# How to display brand name above the product name

Tags: magento-2.1

How can I display the brand name above the product name on the products card?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that the branch attribute is set as `display_in_product_listing`, this will ensure the data is loaded and ready for you to display it in product listing pages. Then you need to find the template which renders the product grid. It's in the Catalog module and it's called `product/view/list.phtml`, There is a loop where products' html is generated, inside the loop get the branch attribute by calling `$product->getData('brand')`